# how to force user to stay in a specific UITextfield

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitextfield, email-validation

inside my app i have an UITextfield to let the user to enter Email Address. I implement the delegate method  `-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField` to check if the user  have had entered a valid Email Address. **The Problem** is how to let the cursor stuck inside the Email Address textfield while the verification method returns false and out when the user enter a valid Email.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing you have the email address checked inside `textFieldDidEndEditing`. Use this logic in that method.

```
if (validEmail)
      {
        // Not a problem and resignFirstResponder
      }

else

      {
       // Show an UIAlertView describing the problem //

       [textField becomeFirstResponder];

      }
```